# How to keep the string in view? A inner wide div in a outer narrow div. The string in the inner wide div

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make the "String-String" in view when it's parent div (.item) in view ?

Code

https://codepen.io/homor/pen/BaLPoQb

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="stage">
        <div class="item">
            String-String
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.stage{
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

.item{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    right: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.stage {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  right: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item span {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="item">
      <span>String-String</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand your requirements to be honest, do you need the text "String-String" to stay fixed/visible when you've scrolled and the yellow strip is partially visible?

Comment: I've updated the code to what I think is what you were asking for.

Comment: :) Thank you very much! It is the best solution.